# Why does my MacBook Pro (8,2, running Yosemite) get so hot?

Tags: macos, mac, fan

This may look like a duplicate, but I've done research and noticed that everyone else is asking why their MacBook Pro Early 2011 (8,2) gets so hot- while they're using it. I constantly have activity monitor open to see if it's working hard and I never get more than 1/4 full- yet my fans are going off like it's a race to see which can spin faster. I also have a Mac Mini that CONSTANTLY hits 100%CPU usage - and I can NEVER hear it's fan. I've tried dusting the fans off, only to find that they were already clean. I've tried looking up possible causes, but it seems that everyone else with this problem is working their mac hard. While typing this, my CPU is at 80% idle and the temp is 163F, with fans at 6192rpm.

Comment: what is an MBP?

Comment: @FrankThomas: MBP = Macbook Pro. Still it would help a lot if he/she mentioned which specific version of it they are talking about.

Comment: ahh. In that case @Op, since you are discussing a notebook, get a cooling plate, and always keep the laptop on a hard flat surface (I keep my laptop on a cooling plate, that is ontop of a cheap cutting board to keep it off my lap, and keep airflow). if that has no big effect, it is likely that your heatsink is no longer  mounted correctly, and should probably be remounted. http://www.insidemylaptop.com/how-to-replace-thermal-grease-on-macbook-pro/

Comment: Sorry, yes I have a MacBook Pro Early 2011 (MacBook Pro 8,2), running Yosemite. I do keep it on a cool flat surface, I'm not afraid of cutting off Airflow because I also keep it angled so that the fans are always as exposed as possible (would be better if the monitor hinge wasn't there blocking them) Would replacing the thermal paste effect it that much? I've read that putting too much or too little will ruin a processor. - Also, thank you for the responses!!

Comment: Reseating the Heatsink is always the last thing you try, due to its difficulty, and because if you have tried everything else, then there is a serious hardware issue that will require replacing critical components, like motherboards, CPUs, and power systems.  Your CPU must be in tight and consistent contact with teh heatsink in order to evacuate heat properly. even shallow scratches on either surface can lead to heat build up. Assuming the laptop has been designed well, and there are no other hardware issues, yes, I would expect reseating the heatsink to be the next step.

Comment: @Rudi It's better to improve the quality of your question by editing it to add that information. Otherwise, it can get lost in the comments. Many users can make the time to read a question but not all the comments.

Comment: @FrankThomas I might be able to reseat my heatsink (or pester my uncle to do it for me, he does computer repair for macs) but are there any other alternatives? Also thank you AnthonyGeoghegan I made the edits you mentioned.

Comment: if its clean, the fans are functioning, air flow has been checked, and the load is low, theres really not much else to do, other than to artificially throttle your system (and if its at 72C from 20% utilization, that may be pointless as well). The cooling system components all appear to be functioning, but are not up to the task of evacuating the heat. Assuming this is not a design flaw, then the only thing you haven't checked is the contact between the CPU die and the heatsink's surface. if that won't do it, the next step is usually a new case, which is tricky for a laptop.

Comment: @FrankThomas Can you post that as an answer so I can select it please? :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2009 MBP and it gets so hot that it's uncomfortable to hold in your lap.

The reason (I believe) is that the aluminum body of the MBP is also a part of the heat-sink and is used to cool the internals.

The fact that the outside is getting hot means it's keeping the inside cool (relatively).

There's not much you can really do about it despite the many things I've read.  I've seen a brand new, CLEAN install (Snow Leopard and above) run hot when the only thing running is the default system software and Chrome.

BTW, videos in Chrome really make the Mac run hot.

Answer (score 0):

@FrankThomas

> if its clean, the fans are functioning, air flow has been checked, and the load is low, theres really not much else to do, other than to artificially throttle your system (and if its at 72C from 20% utilization, that may be pointless as well). The cooling system components all appear to be functioning, but are not up to the task of evacuating the heat. Assuming this is not a design flaw, then the only thing you haven't checked is the contact between the CPU die and the heatsink's surface. if that won't do it, the next step is usually a new case, which is tricky for a laptop.

I'll have to check this out sometime next week. Thank you so much!!